# Change enum type value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, enums

Hello I am using a library. It has some options embedded in enum, but i can't figure out how to configure them. The library is called [PPRevealSideViewController](https://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController/).
It has a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) PPRevealSideOptions options;
```

Here is the enum code:

```
enum {
    PPRevealSideOptionsNone = 0,
    PPRevealSideOptionsShowShadows = 2 << 1, /// Disable or enable the shadows. Enabled by default
    PPRevealSideOptionsBounceAnimations = 1 << 2, /// Decide if the animations are boucing or not. By default, they are
    PPRevealSideOptionsCloseCompletlyBeforeOpeningNewDirection = 1 << 3, /// Decide if we close completely the old direction, for the new one or not. Set to YES by default
    PPRevealSideOptionsKeepOffsetOnRotation = 1 << 4, /// Keep the same offset when rotating. By default, set to no
    PPRevealSideOptionsResizeSideView = 1 << 5, /// Resize the side view. If set to yes, this disabled the bouncing stuff since the view behind is not large enough to show bouncing correctly. Set to NO by default
};
typedef NSUInteger PPRevealSideOptions;
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
obj.options = opt0 | opt1 | ... etc
```

For example: `obj.options = PPRevealSideOptionsBounceAnimations | PPRevealSideOptionsResizeSideView;`

Comment: I still don't get it. How to change PPRevealSideOptionsBounceAnimations to 0 for example, so i can turn off bouncing?

Comment: Options are stored in int and taken like `11001000` - this corresponds to PPRevealSideOptionsShowShadows + PPRevealSideOptionsBounceAnimations + PPRevealSideOptionsResizeSideView. So you should change this int to `10001000`. So you just make `obj.options = obj.options & ~PPRevealSideOptionsBounceAnimations`, using bitwise operations to change value of concrete bit.

Comment: Bitwise operators really? This is very low-level solution. It does work, though but now my shadow is gone along with other options.

Comment: It should not nullify other options. You can try `obj.options &= ~PPRevealSideOptionsBounceAnimations`

Answer (score 1):

I made a documentation of this controller for that purpose. Well, my bad, this method is not very highlighted, but does exist :
You can reset an option using `- (void) resetOption:(PPRevealSideOptions)option;` (behind, it is low level : `_options ^= option;`)
Or set an option by using `- (void) setOption:(PPRevealSideOptions)option`. There is even a setOptionS method ;)